# Exception indexing polygons with solr (jts not found?)

Tags: java, solr, jts, wkt

I'm having trouble setting up solr 4.10.2 to work with polygons. I try to adapt the example application to work with an field called `geom` with the type `location_rpt`. I added jts-1.13.jar to the file `solr-4.10.2/example/webapps/solr.war` in the directory 
`WEB-INF/lib` and I created a field in schema.xml:

```
<field name="geom" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

I start solr with `java -jar start.jar`.

But when I try to add a document with a geom field I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unknown Shape definition [POLYGON ((12.833040666607534 54.00218401664526, 12.83303934146181 54.10218449095831, 12.999714402162988 54.10218524894654, 12...]
at com.spatial4j.core.io.WktShapeParser.parse(WktShapeParser.java:90)
at com.spatial4j.core.context.SpatialContext.readShapeFromWkt(SpatialContext.java:294)
```

It seems that the jts jar is not recognized. Do I have to configure it somewhere?

Regards

Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it: the field definition needs the attribute [`spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search)  or the system property `SpatialContextFactory` must be set to `com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory`.