# Solr - Unknown Shape Definition Error

Tags: solr, spatial, solr4

I am new to Solr and I am trying to setup a local Solr core so that I can perform Spatial searches on it. I am using version 5.2.1. I have updated my schema.xml file to include the location-rpt fieldType:

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
        geo="false" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.001" distanceUnits="degrees" />
```

And I have defined my field to use this type:

```
<field name="positionWkt" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

I also added the jts-1.4.0.jar file to C:\solr-5.2.1\server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib.

However when I try to add a document through the Solr Admin Console I am seeing this response:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 6
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "Unknown Shape definition [POLYGON((-77.23 38.922, -77.23 38.923, -77.228 38.923, -77.228 38.922, -77.23 38.922))]",
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

I can submit documents successfully if I remove the positionWkt field. Did I miss a configuration step? I've looked at the answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041989/exception-indexing-polygons-with-solr-jts-not-found), but my field type definition already contains the SpatialContextFactory and if you add it to the field itself then Solr throws an error.

Here is the document I am trying to add:

```
{
        "observationId": "8e09f47f",
        "observationType": "image",
        "startTime": "2015-09-19T21:03:51Z",
        "endTime": "2015-09-19T21:03:51Z",
        "receiptTime": "2016-07-29T15:49:49.328Z",
        "locationLat": 38.9225015078814,
        "locationLon": -77.22900299194423,
        "position": "38.9225015078814,-77.22900299194423",
        "positionWkt": "POLYGON((-77.23 38.922, -77.23 38.923, -77.228 38.923, -77.228 38.922, -77.23 38.922))",
        "provider": "a"
}
```

Here is the schema.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<schema name="example" version="1.5">

   <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 

   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_is" type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general"   indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_en"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_fs" type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" />
   <dynamicField name="*_dt"  type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_dts" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_p"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_c"   type="currency" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />

    <uniqueKey>observationId</uniqueKey>

    <!-- MY FIELDS -->
    <copyField source="observationId" dest="id"/>
    <!-- 'id' field already defined above. no need to explicitly define again. -->
    <field name="observationId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/> 
    <field name="observationType" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
    <field name="startTime" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
    <field name="endTime" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
    <field name="receiptTime" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
    <field name="locationLat" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
    <field name="locationLon" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
    <field name="position" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="positionWkt" type="location_rpt" indexed="true" stored="true" />

    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_en_splitting_tight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="text_general_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
           maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
        />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" />
    <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldSuffix="_d"/>

    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>

    <fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
        geo="false" distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.001" distanceUnits="degrees" />

    <fieldType name="bbox" class="solr.BBoxField"
               geo="true" distanceUnits="kilometers" numberType="_bbox_coord" />
    <fieldType name="_bbox_coord" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" docValues="true" stored="false"/>

    <fieldType name="currency" class="solr.CurrencyField" precisionStep="8" defaultCurrency="USD" currencyConfig="currency.xml" />
</schema>
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I get the same error when I use the curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/spaceknow/update/json/docs' --data-binary '{"observationId":"8e09f47f", "observationType":"spaceknow", "startTime":"2015-09-19T21:03:51Z", "endTime":"2015-09-19T21:03:51Z", "receiptTime":"2016-07-29T15:49:49.328Z", "locationLat":38.9225015078814, "locationLon":-77.22900299194423, "position":"38.9225015078814,-77.22900299194423", "positionWkt":"POLYGON((-77.23 38.922, -77.23 38.923, -77.228 38.923, -77.228 38.922, -77.23 38.922))", "provider":"a"}'
```

Response:

```
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":3},"error":{"msg":"Unknown Shape definition [POLYGON((-77.23 38.922, -77.23 38.923, -77.228 38.923, -77.228 38.922, -77.23 38.922))]","code":400}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the old jts jar was the problem. When I upgraded to version 1.14 instead of 1.4 the queries work.